# Irreducible quadratic in $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I want to show that for every prime $p$, there exists an irreducible quadratic in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$. So I'm looking for some $x^2+ax+b$ that's irreducible. But what $a,b$ choose we choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $p=2$, use $x^2+x+1$. For $p\gt 2$, find a quadratic non-residue $a$ of $p$, there are many, since half of all numbers between $1$ and $p-1$ are quadratic non-residues of $p$.  Then $x^2-a$ works.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to actually find one. It may be easier to count how many reducible quadratics there are and compare it to how many total quadratics there are

Comment: Quadratic is of the form $x^2+ax+b$, so $p^2$ of them. Reducible ones are $(x+a)(x+b)$, so also $p^2$. How would we find an irreducible one?

Comment: If there is a repeated root it gets counted twice, so you have to subtract p.

Comment: Ok, then we count both $(x+a)(x+b)$ and $(x+b)(x+a)$, so actually even less...

Comment: There are 3 reducible quadratics when $p=2$, so my count is off.

Comment: It must be that you do p choose 2 plus p.